# PostgreSQL multiple expressions in a group?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have a table `product_tag`:

```
product_id | tag_id
-----------+-------
123        | 100
123        | 101
124        | 100
```

I can find all the products that have at least one tag like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
FROM product_tag
WHERE tag_id IN (100, 101)
```

But if I want only the products that have all the tags, I need to add more joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
FROM product_tag pt1, product_tag pt2
WHERE pt1.tag_id = 100 AND pt2.tag_id = 101
```

This gets very painful if there are lots of tags. So I am using this:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM product_tag
WHERE tag_id IN (100, 101)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

This is more friendly to write but isn't so friendly with the query planner. Is there an *approproiate* way in SQL to do this?

Comment: "*but isn't so friendly with the query planner*" - what exactly is the problem? Can you show us the output of `explain analyze`? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: You might also be interested in this: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken and that is the best way to do it. I can't run `analyse` because I'm using these queries in Redshift.

Comment: Assuming that you can't have two identical rows in `product_tag` (e.g. `123, 100` and again `123,100`), then you query with `GROUP BY` would return correct results. It should be pretty efficient as well. Also, unless you are interested in some subset of tags, the `WHERE` clause is not needed. You just need to know in advance the total number of tags and put that number in `HAVING`, as you did.